# Is it possible to output the contents of more than one stream into separate columns in the terminal?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, less-unix

For work, I occasionally need to monitor the output logs of services I create. These logs are short lived, and contain a lot of information that I don't necessarily need.  Up until this point I've been watching them using:

```
grep <tag> * | less
```

where `<tag>` is either INFO, DEBUG, WARN, or ERROR. There are about 10x as many warns as there are errors, and 10x as many debugs as warns, and so forth. It makes it difficult to catch one ERROR in a sea of relevant DEBUG messages. I would like a way to, for instance, make all 'WARN' messages appear on the left-hand side of the terminal, and all the 'ERROR' messages appear on the right-hand side.

I have tried using tmux and screen, but it doesn't seem to be working on my dev machine.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `tail -f <wildcard> | grep <tag>` can be your friend with live logs.

Comment: Have you tried a log filter like `logcheck`?

Comment: Benj: That's more or less what I've been doing, it's hard to catch the few ERRORs amongst the hundreds of INFOs that way though.

Comment: Olaf: I'm limited to default and approved programs on dev stations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
FILE=filename.log
vim -O <(grep 'ERR' "$FILE") <(grep 'WARN' "$FILE")
```

Answer (score 2):

If these are live logs, how about running these two commands in separate terminals:

Errors:

```
tail -f * | grep ERROR
```

Warnings:

```
tail -f * | grep WARN
```

#### Edit

To automate this you could start it in a tmux session. I tend to do this with a tmux script similar to what I described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38488/17666).

In you case the script file could contain something like this:

*monitor.tmux*

```
send-keys "tail -f * | grep ERROR\n"
split
send-keys "tail -f * | grep WARN\n"
```

Then run like this:

```
tmux new -d \; source-file monitor.tmux; tmux attach
```

Comment: I was hoping for something I could alias and just run one command,

Comment: As noted in my original question I can't really use tmux, my dev box is a headless vm being controlled over NX. For some reason or other tmux and screen have unpredictable behavior.

Comment: NX == NoMachine? How about spawning two terminals then, e.g.: `ssh -X host nohup xterm -e 'tail -f * | grep ERROR'` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just use sed to indent the desired lines.  Or, use colors.  For example, to make ERRORS red, you could do:

```
$ r=$( printf '\033[1;31m' )  # escape sequence may change depending on the display
$ g=$( printf '\033[1;32m' )
$ echo $g  # Set the output color to the default
$ sed "/ERROR/ { s/^/$r/; s/$/$g/; }" *
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). Simply split the screen vertically and run `tail -f LOGFILE | grep KEYWORD` on each pane.

As a shortcut, you can use the following rc file:

```
split -v
screen bash -c "tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep ERR"
focus
screen bash -c "tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep WARN"
```

then launch your `screen` instance using:

```
screen -c monitor_log_screen.rc
```

You can of course extend this concept much further by making more splits and use commands like `tail -f` and `watch` to get live updates of different output.

Do also explore screen other screen features such as use of multiple windows (with [monitoring](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Monitor)) and [hardstatus](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Hardstatus) and you can come up with quite a comprehensive "monitoring console".

Comment: As noted in my original question I can't really use screen, my dev box is a headless vm being controlled over NX. For some reason or other tmux and screen have unpredictable behavior.